# How to create an array in javascript using attributes set in the request object?

Tags: javascript

I need to creata an array in javascript, elements for the array should come from server side.

For this what i did was,
In servlet,

```
String[] valuesArray = {"val1","val2","val3"};
request.setAttribute("valuesArray",valuesArray);
```

In Jsp/javaScript: 
`var arrayObj = new Array(${'valuesArray'});`

but,this is not working.. 
Ultimately, arrayObj should contain {"val1","val2","val3"} as elements.
Can someone please suggest where i have gone wrong or let me know how to handle this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here too: http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I havn't found a simpler way to do it. This is how i always did -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var arrayOb = new Array();
   <%
      String[] list = (String[])request.getAttribute("valuesArray");
      for(int count=0; count <list.length; count++) {
   %>
         arrayOb[<%= count %>]='<%= list[count] %>';//dont miss the single quotes here
   <% } %>
</script>
```

Pay close attention to all quotes and scriplet tag.

You can also use jsp for loop or c:for instead of scriplet here.